# Sessions and file upload between Drupal and Android

Tags: android, drupal, file-upload, service

I'm trying to upload an image file from an android device to my drupal website using services module

I can log-in succesfully:

```
HttpParams connectionParameters =  new BasicHttpParams(); 
int timeoutConnection = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(connectionParameters, timeoutConnection);                 
int timeoutSocket = 5000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(connectionParameters, timeoutSocket);

httpClient   =   new DefaultHttpClient(connectionParameters);
HttpPost httpPost       =   new HttpPost(serverUrl+"user/login");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();    

try{
     json.put("password", editText_Password.getText().toString());
     json.put("username", editText_UserName.getText().toString());                          
     StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
     se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

     httpPost.setEntity(se);                       

     //Execute HTTP post request
     HttpResponse response    =   httpClient.execute(httpPost);   
     int status_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();                            

     ... 
     ...

}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

via response object I can get session name session id , user id and many other info.

after the login , I set no session info by myself through my HttpGet object , but use the same DefaultHttpClient,  I can magically retrieve a node using the following code:

`HttpGet httpPost2 = new HttpGet(serverUrl+"node/537.json"); 
HttpResponse response2    =   httpClient.execute(httpPost2);`

this made me think that, httpClient object stored the session info for me automatically.
because if I dont login first or use a new HttpClient object and try to retrieve the node, I get a 401 error.

However when I try to upload an image file as follows after logging in:

```
   httpPost = new HttpPost(serverUrl+"file/");
   json = new JSONObject();
   JSONObject fileObject = new JSONObject();    

   fileObject.put("file", photodata); //photodata is a byte[] that is set before this point
   fileObject.put("filename", "myfirstfile");
   fileObject.put("filepath", "sites/default/files/myfirstimage.jpg");
   json.put("file", fileObject);            

   se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
   se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
   httpPost.setEntity(se);      

   //Execute HTTP post request
   response    =   httpClient.execute(httpPost);   
   status_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

I get 401 error although I'm logged in and using the same HttpClient object.

I also tried adding :

```
httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", SessionName+"="+sessionID);
```

which again gives me 401 error.

I'm also not sure whether I'm using the correct url, because I'm trying to use file.create method, but writing the url as "myip:myport/rest/file/create" gives wrong address.
My aim is to upload an image to a users node, so I guess after succesfully adding the file, I'll use node.create right?

I hope someone will help me get through this.

Comment: can u please help me for the same problem? Please check the below comment.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found when I first started doing this that most of my errors were due to not authenticating correctly.. I'm not *sure* your method is correct.. I know this works.

Using Drupal Services 3, I login as such and then store my session cookie into shared preferences.  dataOut is a JSON object which holds the needed user login, and password information.

```
String uri = URL + ENDPOINT + "user/login";
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
StringEntity se;
try {
     se = new StringEntity(dataOut.toString());
     se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json"));
     httppost.setEntity(se);
     HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httppost);
     mResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
     // save the sessid and session_name
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(mResponse);
     SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.putString("cookie", obj.getString("session_name") + "="
                    + obj.getString("sessid"));
     editor.putLong("sessionid_timestamp", new Date().getTime() / 100);
     editor.commit();
} catch { //all of my catches here }
```

Once I have my session id stored.. I go about performing tasks on drupal like this.. The following code posts a node.  I use the function getCookie() to grab the session cookie if it exists.. if not, then I log in, or if it's expired, I log in.  (note, you need to set the cookie expire time in your drupal settings.php file (I think that's where it is if I remember correctly)

```
String uri = URL + ENDPOINT + "node";
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
String cookie = this.getCookie(mCtx);
httppost.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);
StringEntity se;
try {
    se = new StringEntity(dataOut.toString());
httppost.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httppost);
    // response is here if you need it.
// mResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
} catch { //catches }
```

The getCookie() function that keeps your cookie uptodate and working..

```
/**
 * Takes the current time, the sessid and determines if we are still part of
 * an active session on the drupal server.
 * 
 * @return boolean
 * @throws InternetNotAvailableException
 * @throws ServiceNotAvailableException
 */
protected String getCookie(Context ctx)
        throws InternetNotAvailableException {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
    Long timestamp = settings.getLong("sessionid_timestamp", 0);
    Long currenttime = new Date().getTime() / 100;
    String cookie = settings.getString("cookie", null);
            //mSESSION_LIFETIME is the session lifetime set on my drupal server
    if (cookie == null || (currenttime - timestamp) >= mSESSION_LIFETIME) {

                    // the following are the classes I use to login.
                    // the important code is listed above.
                    // mUserAccount is the JSON object holding login, 
                    // password etc.
        JSONObject mUserAccount = UserAccount.getJSONUserAccount(ctx);
        call(mUserAccount, JSONServerClient.USER_LOGIN);

        return getCookie(ctx);
    } else {
        return cookie;
    }
}
```

This really should enable you to take advantage of all that Services has to offer.  Make sure your endpoints are correct, and also make sure your permissions are set.  I cursed for hours before I realized I had not granted perms to make nodes to users.

So once you are logged in.. To upload a file to Drupal Services I use the following code to first convert the image to byteArray.. and then to Base64.

```
tring filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/test.jpg";
imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath));
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray(); 
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Once you have the encodedImage.  Construct a JSON Object with the keys, file (required), filename (optional, but recommended), filesize (optional) and uid (optional, the poster I presume)  JSON would therefore look like this at its simplist required form {"file":encodedImage}.  Then, after making sure you have enabled the file resource on your server, POST the data to my-server/rest-endpoint/file.  The response will include a fid in JSON.  You can then assign this fid to the image field of a node you subsequently create using the node resource.

Comment: Okay, found this http://drupanium.org/api/82  It does appear the file needs to be encoded Base64, then uploaded to server, then the returned file id (fid) can be assigned to the image field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.. But somehow the "unautherized : acces denied for user" error was caused not by autherization nor login nor permissions but because I was only passing "file" data as parameter.
Since they were told to be optional , I wasn't passing uid and filename. But if I don't send them I get 401 unauthorized error.
So if there is anyone getting this, while uploading file, do not forget to pass uid and filename as well as Base64 encoded string of file data.
filepath and filesize are optional (for at least my case).

Comment: @ToddPainton Hi,I am also facing problem for the send image to server.My image json structure` field_founder_image":[
   {
     "fid":"171",
    "filepath":"sites/cheerfoolz.com/files/fish_0.jpg"
   }
   ],` First i have question what is fid?, but after read this article I got some idea, but when I post `{"file":encodedImage}.` that time logcat did not display whole json responce.and give me status code `406`

Comment: When I print the String value of the encodedImage and then after I convert into json structure that time I can't see the whole encodedImage into json value.

Comment: @RahulPatel I couldn't understand your problem, I'd be glad to help if you give me more details.